# Xamarin.IOS Wireless Deploy to IDevice

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I was interested to see this in the release notes :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-relnotes

Wireless deployment and debugging for Xamarin.iOS.

But my phone would only show up when plugged in via USB!

How to sort this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- Go to iTunes with your Device plugged into USB
- Select your Device
- Under Summary
- Check "Sync with this IDevice over Wi-Fi", click Apply / Done
- Unplug your Device, And you should see it appear in the devices with a WIFI icon next to it :)
- [image]

Update

- I just went "back to front" searching in the Xamarin Docs! and saw this
  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/wireless-deployment/